# Is there a way to get data from mysql with a variable and be able to use it in an if statement for a login system

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

In the select statements I need to select the username and password from the `data` table in my database based on the users input, the input is retrieved from the `userget` and `passget` variables. I'm aware that it gets all the data from the username and password tables but I'm unsure on how to make it only get what the user inputs.

```
def loginpage():
    def login():
        userget = textinput.get()
        passget = textinput2.get()
        
        

        usercheck = mycursor.execute("SELECT `username` FROM `data`")
        u = mycursor.fetchall()
        print(str(u))

        passcheck = mycursor.execute("SELECT `password` FROM `data`")
        p = mycursor.fetchall()
        print(str(p))

        
        if u == userget and p == passget:
            correctscreen = Tk()
            correctscreen.configure(background='yellow')
            correctscreen.title("Correct")
            correctscreen.geometry("300x200")
            labelc = Label(correctscreen, text="Successfully logged in!")
            labelc.pack()
            buttonc = Button(correctscreen, text="Ok", command=correctscreen.destroy)
            buttonc.pack()
            url = 'https://thepugweb.epizy.com/login.html'
            buttonc1 = Button(correctscreen, text="Ok", command=webbrowser.open(url))
        else:
            incorrectscreen = Tk()
            incorrectscreen.configure(background='pink')
            incorrectscreen.title("Incorrect Details")
            incorrectscreen.geometry("300x200")
            labeli = Label(incorrectscreen, text="Incorrect Details Entered")
            labeli.pack()
            buttoni = Button(incorrectscreen, text="Close", command=incorrectscreen.destroy)
            buttoni.pack()
```

Comment: 2 things wrong with your code: First `command=webbrowser.open(url)` should be `command=lambda: webbrowser.open(url)` and second you never call `buttonc1.pack()`.

Comment: When I use .pack() on the end of the buttonc1 variable It returns an error in later functions but when I use it in the way I have it works without problems, I've changed the webbrowser.open statement.

Comment: Oh, I had the wrong button variable in mind but the buttonc1 should have been removed already so there'd be no use packing it since I'll remove it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one SQL statement to get what you want:

```py
def loginpage():
    def login():
        userget = textinput.get()
        passget = textinput2.get()

        mycursor.execute("SELECT 1 FROM `data` WHERE `username`=%s AND `password`=%s", (userget, passget))
        rows = mycursor.fetchall()
        if rows:
            # login successful
            ...
        else:
            # login failed
            ...
```

Comment: "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType and 'int'" is the error I get now

Comment: Which module do you use to connect MySQL?

Comment: I use xampp control panel.

Comment: What I mean is Python module.  Anyway answer updated.